# Automatically remove colinear variables using correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, correlation

I am trying to iteratively and automatically create pairs of independent variables that are correlated based on a matrix, which I will then put into a regression model to remove the least significant one of the pair.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
#Correlation testing on only numeric variables
num.cols <- bind.data[,sapply(bind.data, is.numeric),with=FALSE]
cor.matrix <- cor(num.cols,use="complete.obs")

#Create a table of all pairings of potentially colinear variables
#start the process by hardcoding the first 2 iterations
cor.vars1 <- expand.grid(var1 = colnames(cor.matrix)[1], 
                     var2 = row.names(cor.matrix[which((abs(cor.matrix[,1]) > cor.cutoff) & (abs(cor.matrix[,1]) != 1)),]))
cor.vars1 <- as.data.table(cor.vars1)

cor.vars2 <- expand.grid(var1 = colnames(cor.matrix)[2], 
                     var2 = row.names(cor.matrix[which((abs(cor.matrix[,2]) > cor.cutoff) & (abs(cor.matrix[,2]) != 1)),]))
cor.vars2 <- as.data.table(cor.vars2)
cor.vars <- rbind(cor.vars1, cor.vars2)

#now create for-loop to automatically do the rest
for (i in 3:length(num.cols)) {
  cor.varsn <- expand.grid(var1 = colnames(cor.matrix)[i], 
                       var2 = row.names(cor.matrix[which((abs(cor.matrix[,i]) > cor.cutoff) & (abs(cor.matrix[,i]) != 1)),]))
  cor.vars <- rbind(cor.vars, cor.varsn)
}
```

The basic idea is for every column in the correlation matrix, I want an expand grid made of the column name and every row name of variables with correlations to the column variable greater than some cutoff "cor.cutoff". I will do this for each column and rbind them all. At the end I will have a 2-column data.table where each row represents a pairing of correlated independent predictor variables.

My problem is that the for-loop breaks when it gets to a column with no correlations to other variables. Rather than skipping on to the next column that fulfills the requirement, it stops completely. Is there an elegant way to do this rather than an "if" statement? Particularly when the first column is the problem (i.e. cor.vars1 or cor.vars2 have no correlations to other variables.

Comment: If you have collinearity issues, only looking at pairwise correlations may not solve everything. You'd be better served by something like the Variance Inflation Factor, see `car::vif`.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `next` command. You'll still have to use it with an `if` statement. (What's inelegant about an if statement??) Run `for (i in 1:5) {if(i == 3) next; print(i)}`

Comment: Temporarily disregarding @Gregor's point about actual relevance, have you taken a look at `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)`? For example, try `which(mtcars > 200, arr.ind = TRUE)`. It gives an expansion of row/col pairs that meet a specific criterion.

Comment: Another approach would be to use the bicreg function from the BMA package which will select an optimal set of variables for you.

Comment: How well does the VIF package handle NAs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
rmcl = function(cor_mat, threshold) {
  cor_mat = abs(cor_mat)
  stopifnot(sum(cor_mat[is.na(cor_mat)]) == 0) 
  for (i in 1:(nrow(cor_mat) - 1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):ncol(cor_mat)) {
      if(cor_mat[i, j] > threshold) {
        cor_mat[i, ] = rep(NA, ncol(cor_mat))
        break
      }
    }
  }
  idx = which(!is.na(cor_mat[, 1]))
  cor_mat[idx, idx]
}
```

The trick is to preserve the shape of the correlation matrix so that the iteration can continue.

An example:

```
data = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100), x3 = rnorm(100))
# the last 3 columns are in perfect correlation with the first 3.
data$x4 = 2 * data$x1
data$x5 = 2 * data$x2
data$x6 = 2 * data$x3
c = cor(data)
c = rmcl(c, .9)
c


          x4         x5         x6
x4 1.0000000 0.08847400 0.03297110
x5 0.0884740 1.00000000 0.09915481
x6 0.0329711 0.09915481 1.00000000
```